# How to Grab multiple values from checkboxes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input

I currently have this form

```
 <form class='lostKittieForm'>


      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="Black">Black</label>
      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="Brown">Brown</label>
      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="White">White</label>
      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="Gray">Gray</label>
      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="Orange">Orange</label>
      <label class="kittieColor"><input type="checkbox" value="Multicolored">Multicolored</label>

      <input type="submit">

 </form>
```

My Jquery code is trying to grab all the values checked but for some reason it's only grabbing one and "Black"

```
 kittie.color =  $(".lostKittieForm input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("checkbox").each(function(e){

var checkVal = $(this).val();

});
```

OR

```
$('.lostKittieForm input:checked').each(function() {
    var checkVal = $(this).val();
}); // will return the value for "checked" checkboxes
```

The loop will run for each checkbox and you can get the value of every  checkbox in checkVal Variable one by one .

for Documentation of .each()  go to .

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

`kittie.color = $("input:checked").each(function() {alert($(this).val());});`

here is the code to get the value

Comment: This worked too! thank you! It's alerting the values though. Would I need to store all that into a varieable such as x and then x = kittie.color ?

Comment: yes. you can declare a array variable outside that function. Something like this.

`var color_list = [];
kittie.color = $("input:checked").each(function({color_list.push($(this).val());});`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var kittieColor = new Array();
$('.kittieColor').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
        kittieColor.push($(this).find('input').val());
    }         
});

alert(JSON.stringify(kittieColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop

```
var colorsChecked = [];
$('input:checkbox.class').each(function () {
      colorsChecked.push(this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```